# How to visualise data from highest > lowest on Python (Jupyter Notebook?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, visualization, data-science

For example I have -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = dataset[['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC']].plot(kind='bar', title ='Dataset Title', figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Example", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

But the results visualise the data in the order of the dataframe. Is there a way to visualise the data so that for example it rearranges the entries and orders them left > right highest > lowest? (or similar?) To make it easier to view the order of highest > lowest at first glance?

Many thanks. :)

Comment: Format your question and code properly for help people better understand you.

Comment: Do you want to order by one specific column? Or for every row a new order?

Comment: @erocoar is there a way to order by one specific column? For example If I just visualised 'columnA' is there a way to show the data in the bar chart from highest > lowest, rather than the order it appears in the CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `sort_values`.

```
ax = dataset[['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC']].sort_values("columnA", ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', title ='Dataset Title', figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: hey btw do you know if there's a way to order all of the columns from highest to lowest?